# Epic ( Eclipse ) Perl not working

Tags: eclipse, perl, epic

I have installed Epic in my Eclipse to run perl scripts. Unfortunately, iam getting the below error while trying to run the script.

> Failed to execute command line: "perl" "-v"
>
> Cannot run program "perl" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

When i tried to run "perl -v" in command prompt, it worked fine on the day i installed Epic. After restarting, the command does not work and the folder `C:\Dwimperl` became empty.

- Note : The script did not run and showed the same error in eclipse even on the day i installed Epic.

> I am using Windows 7, Eclipse Luna Release 2(4.4.2), and Perl 5 (before restart, now deleted)
>
> These are the contents of my System PATH

```
E:\app\mevenk\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32??\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool
%JAVA_HOME%\
C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
%M2_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: We need a lot more information: What OS are you using? Which version of Eclipse? Which version of perl? Which version of Epic? Is perl in your system path?

Comment: windows 7; Eclipse Luna Release 2(4.4.2); perl 5 (before restart,now deleted)

Comment: Could you also post your system path? 1) Start the System Control Panel applet (Start - Settings - Control Panel - System). 2) Select the Advanced tab. 3) Click the Environment Variables button. 4) Under System Variables, select Path, and copy paste it.

Comment: E:\app\mevenk\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;%JAVA_HOME%\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;%M2_HOME%\bin;

Comment: uninstalled and installed again.But the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not already done, In the eclipse perl EPIC preferences you need to set the full path to your perl interpreter:

e.g. In my Eclipse I have:

Window -> Preferences-> Perl EPIC-> Perl executable = "C:\DEV\TOOLS\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe"

Comment: yeah,this would be the common problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved after installing ActivePerl.
The problem is with perl Interpreter given with Epic (Dwimperl) which did not set the PATH variables and installables properly.

After installing ActivePerl, Eclipse took its path variables.

> C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;

Now, perl scripts working fine in Eclipse.